# Do not dispose objects multiple times

Tags: memory-management, fxcop, .net

Can't seem to see why FXCop is complaining that I am disposing the memoryStream object more than once. As near as I can tell, I'm only disposing of it in the finally block.

Full error message is:

CA2202  Do not dispose objects multiple times   Object 'memoryStream' can be disposed more than once in method 'MessageTransform.GetEnvelope(Message)'. To avoid generating a System.ObjectDisposedException you should not call Dispose more than one time on an object.: Lines: 48    Api MessageTransform.cs 48

```
        var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
        try
        {
            var messageBuffer = message.CreateBufferedCopy(int.MaxValue);
            var xPathNavigator = messageBuffer.CreateNavigator();

            var xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(memoryStream);
            xPathNavigator.WriteSubtree(xmlWriter);
            xmlWriter.Flush();
            xmlWriter.Close();

            memoryStream.Position = 0;
            var xdoc = XDocument.Load(XmlReader.Create(memoryStream));
            return xdoc;
        }
        catch (ApplicationException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            return null;
        }
        finally
        {
            memoryStream.Dispose();
        }
```

If I wrap the same code in a using block I get the same error.

> ```
> using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
> {
>     var messageBuffer = message.CreateBufferedCopy(int.MaxValue);
>     var xPathNavigator = messageBuffer.CreateNavigator();
>
>     var xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(memoryStream);
>     xPathNavigator.WriteSubtree(xmlWriter);
>     xmlWriter.Flush();
>     xmlWriter.Close();
>
>     memoryStream.Position = 0;
>     var xdoc = XDocument.Load(XmlReader.Create(memoryStream));
>     return xdoc;
> }
> ```

Is this just an issue with a hyperactive FXCop or does using a using block or .Dispose() somehow not apply to a System.IO.MemoryStream?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `XmlWriter` can dispose the stream from its `Close` method, which is what the rule is picking up.  However, this behavior is conditional and should not be invoked in an `XmlWriter` created for a stream in the way you describe.

Answer (score 1):

As Nicole described, the `XmlWriters'` `Close` can dispose the `Memorystream`-object, which is causing the error to be raised.

I do want to point out that a `using` statement and `try-finally`statement are the exact same thing. The compiler translates using statements into a tryblock with your execution and a Dispose() in the finallyblock.